# How to remove a file from GIT if it doen't exist any more

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

I was trying to use git and git-hub for my first time;

and there was a file that I wanted to change it's name so I just changed it and committed then when I pushed it but it says :

`[rejected]        main -> main (fetch first) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/MyUserName/MyProjectName.git' hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

so I just added `-f` to force but it made another directory holding the old name of the file so I delete it but every time I do `push` command it just makes the same thing

how can I get rid of this old file once and for ever
thanks.

Comment: Did you actually read the error? It suggested you do a git pull before pushing.

Comment: @mason I actually did but it didn't get me any pull requests in the git-hub page

Comment: Running git pull does not retrieve pull requests. It pulls down commits that were previously pushed up to the remote.

Comment: @mason oh this why the the old file shows on my directory when I did it ... so what to do after I have the files on my directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the latest version of the GitHub repository before pushing local changes.

```
git pull
```

After this make the changes you wish to make on the local repository (Changing the file name in this case)

Then :-

```
git commit -am "Message"
git push
```